# Error while scrolling custom listview with textview and imageview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to display a custom listview. Each single row contains a textview and an imageview. I have tried much on this code but still not able to understand the problem with this. The problem is, while i scroll the list it selects the other item in the list. In short, it does not store the previous state of the imageview.
I need this mechanism because i want make my activity work like "Deleting multiple items by selecting them from the list".
If anyone could help me with this, please...

```
package com.walletapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DeleteData extends Activity {

    Cursor cursor;
    ListView lv_delete_data;
    static ArrayList<Integer> listOfItemsToDelete;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Category[] categories;
    ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
    private ArrayAdapter<Category> listAdapter;
    ImageView iv_delete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete_data);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        manage_reload_list();

        listOfItemsToDelete = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        iv_delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDeleteDataDelete);
        iv_delete.setClickable(true);
        iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listOfItemsToDelete.isEmpty()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No items selected.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else {
                    showDialog(
                            "Warning",
                            "Are you sure you want to delete these categories ? This will erase all records attached with it.");
                }
            }
        });

        lv_delete_data = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDeleteData);
        lv_delete_data.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    private void showDialog(String title, String message) {

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new Builder(DeleteData.this);
        adb.setTitle(title);
        adb.setMessage(message);
        adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        String btn = "Ok";
        if (title.equals("Warning")) {
            btn = "Yes";
            adb.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

        adb.setPositiveButton(btn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                for (int i : listOfItemsToDelete) {
                    // -------first delete from category table-----

                    database.delete("category", "cat_id=?", new String[] { i
                            + "" });

                    // ---------delete from category_fields

                    database.delete("category_fields", "cat_id=?",
                            new String[] { i + "" });

                    // ---------delete from records_data-------

                    database.delete("records_data", "cat_id=?",
                            new String[] { i + "" });
                }

                database.close();
                manage_reload_list();
                lv_delete_data.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
        ad.show();
    }

    protected void manage_reload_list() {

        loadDatabase();

        categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();

        // ------first fetch all categories name list-------

        cursor = database.query("category", new String[] { "cat_id",
                "cat_description" }, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            showDialog("Error", "No categories found.");
            cursor.close();
        } else {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                categories = new Category[] { new Category(cursor.getInt(0),
                        cursor.getString(1)) };
                categoryList.addAll(Arrays.asList(categories));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        listAdapter = new CategoryArrayAdapter(this, categoryList);
    }

    public static class Category {
        String cat_name = "";
        int cat_id = 0;
        Boolean checked = false;

        Category(int cat_id, String name) {
            this.cat_name = name;
            this.cat_id = cat_id;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return cat_id;
        }

        public String getCatName() {
            return cat_name;
        }

        public Boolean getChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public void toggleChecked() {
            checked = !checked;
        }
    }

    private static class CategoryViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageViewCheck;
        private TextView textViewCategoryName;

        public CategoryViewHolder(ImageView iv_check, TextView tv_category_name) {
            imageViewCheck = iv_check;
            textViewCategoryName = tv_category_name;
        }

        public ImageView getImageViewCheck() {
            return imageViewCheck;
        }

        public TextView getTextViewCategoryName() {
            return textViewCategoryName;
        }
    }

    private static class CategoryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CategoryArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categoryList) {
            super(context, R.layout.single_row_delete_data,
                    R.id.textViewSingleRowDeleteData, categoryList);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Category category = (Category) this.getItem(position);
            final ImageView imageViewCheck;
            final TextView textViewCN;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_delete_data,
                        null);

                imageViewCheck = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageViewSingleRowDeleteData);
                textViewCN = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleRowDeleteData);

                convertView.setTag(new CategoryViewHolder(imageViewCheck,
                        textViewCN));
            }

            else {
                CategoryViewHolder viewHolder = (CategoryViewHolder) convertView
                        .getTag();
                imageViewCheck = viewHolder.getImageViewCheck();
                textViewCN = viewHolder.getTextViewCategoryName();
            }

            imageViewCheck.setFocusable(false);
            imageViewCheck.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            imageViewCheck.setClickable(true);
            imageViewCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
                    Category category = (Category) iv.getTag();

                    if (category.getChecked() == false) {
                        imageViewCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_check);
                        listOfItemsToDelete.add(category.getId());
                        category.setChecked(true);
                    } else {
                        imageViewCheck
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.set_basecircle);
                        listOfItemsToDelete.remove((Integer) category.getId());
                        category.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            });
            imageViewCheck.setTag(category);
            textViewCN.setText(category.getCatName());

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private void loadDatabase() {
        database = openOrCreateDatabase("WalletAppDatabase.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

This is my logcat output:

```
04-11 08:32:47.083: D/dalvikvm(1261): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 735K, 29% free 3332K/4672K, paused 199ms, total 205ms
04-11 08:32:47.362: E/ActivityThread(1261): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
04-11 08:32:47.632: I/Ads(1261): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":18,"session_id":"5201479258687953639","seq_num":"19","slotname":"a1512f50d8c3692","u_w":320,"msid":"com.walletapp","cap":"m,a","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.3.0","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.walletapp","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"kw":[],"u_sd":1,"simulator":1,"ms":"5j2LTo7Vhgatbr2zw9EGXbWGmAc8VRgJRTZpfRmRxDNZMDEtohADcdSvAbGyjHBAH6KuyP48dzaU-_Gfkq8adRJMFxu5Oq_46jWdTHBUpf_Fgm5xN1ehJ8NcEhqNpN7oHsV38ukGuVQUNKofxsk0Ij8cY8l0_QddW8iKCAXhz80Ujr2xbTEzUd9nV9NGfq1EBiaZjk732PJPl7Z2Myy1oX61Bk7VZzpSyCtlX5XIzdTM8iyqsNk2yTmjG6sflKdqXykfd1oXnrlrxaDLHnq1C4cSceFeDQZ0Lv-oxG2Xzr76GT9BhyUEWzE7pTYJQ70-KpUOV2Il56LykY3wCH2j2Q","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":480,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":1851610});</script></head><body></body></html>
04-11 08:32:48.321: D/webviewglue(1261): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a368740
04-11 08:32:48.392: I/Choreographer(1261): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 08:32:49.052: I/Choreographer(1261): Skipped 396 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 08:32:55.001: I/Choreographer(1261): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 08:33:29.022: E/Ads(1261): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (http://media.admob.com/:1)
04-11 08:33:29.022: E/Web Console(1261): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined at http://media.admob.com/:1
04-11 08:33:47.529: I/Ads(1261): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
04-11 08:33:47.531: D/webviewglue(1261): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a368740
04-11 08:33:47.541: I/Ads(1261): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
04-11 08:34:47.581: I/Ads(1261): Refreshing ad.
04-11 08:34:47.622: E/ActivityThread(1261): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
04-11 08:34:47.762: I/Ads(1261): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":19,"session_id":"5201479258687953639","seq_num":"20","slotname":"a1512f50d8c3692","u_w":320,"msid":"com.walletapp","cap":"m,a","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.3.0","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.walletapp","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"kw":[],"u_sd":1,"simulator":1,"ms":"Trn0wt2c5XiO7OmFyXqrKSLD7ZgZh_ZbxneDNRsJ5MwCcYQbDy7isjpET_A9DTjPoNNPXVDn41qPQDD5Msbcr6ieK1Rchi6ctbf3FTZcO5QSlr054zlHBS2qx7jL-T9VwVNde2CNfbgy_6_w5Ww85XfPo9L2TaZqmg49knQiBxg_gw3fijmphjz0LYqrhjuc8XLVG2K9z27UwQA4_2KGoiM5iwxXsXO0L2LT-3BXz49GyD3r9XZ8qHI4nrIQ2pPsEWUhgznx4I24PAvvwmOEcF0DVLzndhPwaj-HlI5f6-vXHGFQ6hxU6iV58DytEWEbF9eI1Ierr_4Eue0rqFkoyw","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":480,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":480,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":1971778});</script></head><body></body></html>
04-11 08:35:28.222: E/Ads(1261): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (http://media.admob.com/:1)
04-11 08:35:28.222: E/Web Console(1261): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined at http://media.admob.com/:1
04-11 08:35:47.714: I/Ads(1261): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
04-11 08:35:47.714: D/webviewglue(1261): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a240398
04-11 08:35:47.741: I/Ads(1261): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

I am not getting any kind of error.
I am newbie, but still i have tried my best to find the mistake in my code, but unsuccessful. Please help me...

Comment: show the logcat output, without it no one will be able to help you here.

Comment: Without getting any error how can i show you the logcat output of this activity..!!! Still i did some operations and showed the output. Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your adapter into this model, I think this helps you,

```
public class CheckBoxInListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context=null;
private List<ArrayListObjects> searchArrayList=null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater=null;
private ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();

public CheckBoxInListAdapter(Context context, List<ArrayListObjects> mData) 
{
    this.context=context;
    searchArrayList = mData;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
public int getCount() 
{
    return searchArrayList.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
     if (convertView == null) 
     {
          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_layout,null);
          holder=new ViewHolder();
          holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
          holder.itemNormalChecked=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
          convertView.setTag(holder);
     } 
     else 
     {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }
     holder.textView.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getItemName());
     holder.itemNormalChecked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(searchArrayList.get(position).isItemChecked())
            {
                searchArrayList.get(position).setItemChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                searchArrayList.get(position).setItemChecked(true);
            }
        }
     });
     if(searchArrayList.get(position).isItemChecked())
     {
         holder.itemNormalChecked.setChecked(true);
     }
     else
     {
         holder.itemNormalChecked.setChecked(false);
     }
     return convertView;
 }
 static class ViewHolder
 {
     TextView textView=null;
     CheckBox itemNormalChecked=null;
 }
}
```